# Java Ear application - Hot deployment

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, weblogic, hotdeploy

I deploy my application as ear in to weblogic. Even for a small change i need to build and restart my server. I am looking out for an easier solution where i could hot deploy my current changes.

I had already tried deploying ear as an open directory.
Can any body help me with this

Answer (score 0):

weblogic uses a value in MANIFEST.MF to determine if the package to be deployed is a newer version of the current deployment. the value is 'Weblogic-Application-Version'. if you update this value, you can redeploy your ear file without stopping-starting the managed instance.

for more info: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11035_01/wls100/deployment/redeploy.html)